# How to join two table with different fields to a single table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

```
ORDERS
    OrderID    CustomerID    OrderDate
    543        2             2015-09-18
    621        37            2016-09-19
    209        77            2016-09-20

CUSTOMERS
    CustomerName    Country
    Alen            Germany
    Ana             Mexico
    Lisa            India
```

I want to join both tables in a new table named CustomerOrders as following format:

```
OrderID    CustomerID  OrderDate      CustomerName    Country
543        2           2015-09-18     Alen            Germany
621        37          2016-09-19     Ana             Mexico
209        77          2016-09-20     Lisa            India
```

How to list all records from two different tables to a new table?

Comment: You have no key in Cutomers table (like a... customerID) ?

Comment: customers table must conatining customerid field to be used for joining else not possible

Comment: you can't because there isn't a relationship between the two

Comment: First make a key to map them both then only you can achive that.

Answer (score 0):

You known about database normalization? You known about "first normal form", "second normal form"?

I don't explain it now. All explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you customer table has primary key customer_id.

`select o.order_id,c.customer_name,o.order_date, c.customer_id, c.country o.* from orders o left join customers c on o.customer_id=c.customer_id`